# Problem getting desired output using Grep with just numbers as pattern

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I am trying to grep rows from a file 2 that matches the values in file 1, but output is giving more lines.

File 1 looks like this:

```
$ head b.txt
5
11
26
27
```

File 2, `a.txt`, looks like

```
1509 5
1506 11
1507 12
339 26
1000 27
1000 100
```

Command I use:

```
grep -wFf b.txt a.txt
```

Results I want:

```
1509 5
1506 11
339 26
1000 27
```

It is giving me all I have in `b.txt`, but some extra lines too, e.g.,

```
1509 5
1506 11
1507 12
339 26
1000 27
1000 100
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, with your example input files and the command you show, I get your desired output.

Comment: Do you expect the contents of `a.txt` to be modified by grep, perhaps?

Comment: yes i get desired output with small section of file like this but if i give entire file it gives 5012 instead of 5000 lines

Comment: Can you reduce the files to a few lines that reproduce your problem? Find a line that shouldn't show up in the output, but does, and add it to the example so people can reproduce the issue?

Comment: i tried   "a line that shouldn't show up in the output, but does" .   but with small file it gives no problem. however if i use it within BigFile the error appear. anyways i will for now use "join command"  and later will check it.

Answer (score 5):

I simulated your problem and believe I know what's going on.  With an empty line at the end of `b.txt`, I get the same output as you do.  If I remove the empty line at the end of `b.txt`, I get your desired output.

```
➜  ~ grep -wFf b.txt a.txt
1509 5
1506 11
339 26
1000 27
```

From grep's manpage:

> **`-f file, --file=file`**
>                Read one or more newline separated patterns from file.  **Empty pattern lines match every input line.**  Newlines are not considered part of a pattern.  If `file` is empty, nothing
>                is matched.

I believe the `Empty pattern lines match every input line.` is the cause of your erroneous output.

Comment: can i attach my files here as i checked there is no Empty pattern Line. I am trying but unable to attach

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to join files.

```
join -12 -21 -o1.1,1.2 <(<a.txt sort -k2) <(<b.txt sort)
```

will output:

```
1506 11
339 26
1000 27
1509 5
```

The command joins the second field from a.txt with the second field from b.txt. "joins" means finds specified fields in both files, where they have equal value. I "join" those two files on the second column from the first file and on the first column from the second file. `join` needs the inputs to be sorted by the joined fields, so we need to pipe it through sort. This method sadly will not preserve the order of the lines in files, as they need to be reordered for join to work.

Comment: Thank you it is difficult to understand but worked fine